# What is the maximum memory (RAM) limit for Solaris 11?

Tags: unix, memory, solaris, memory-limit

I have been trying to find out the maximum memory limit for Solaris 11 for a report that I am doing but with no luck. Can anyone please help?

Comment: You can always send a message to Oracle to ask them. If you don't need precise numbers... it'll likely be [far higher than you'll find physically possible](http://superuser.com/questions/168114/how-much-memory-can-a-64bit-machine-address-at-a-time) for at least the next few years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle marketing says that [*The new Virtual Memory subsystem ("VM2") scales now to 100+ TB Memory ranges*](https://blogs.oracle.com/orasysat/entry/what_s_new_in_solaris) though currently the largest machine Oracle sells to run Solaris on is the [SPARC M6-32](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/servers-storage/servers/sparc/oracle-sparc/m6-32/overview/index.html) which can “only” take up to 32 TB of RAM.